# Monitoring voltage for over 10 seconds

Tags: c++, arduino

I am building a program that measure the voltage of a component. When the potential is under 1 V, the vibration motor will turn on.

But my problem is, I want the Arduino to turn on the motor, if the voltage has been under 1 V for 10 seconds or more. For example, if the voltage level is under 1 V for 8 seconds and then it changes to over 5 V again, the motor should not turn on. Also, the motor should turn off after 3 seconds of vibration. I am able to satisfy the first condition.. but I'm not able to turn off the motor.

Here is my code so far:

```cpp
int Pin = 2;
const float baselineVoltage = 200.0;
int belowBaselineVoltage = false;
unsigned long turnOnAt = 10000;
const unsigned long turnOnDelay = 10 * 1000;
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(Pin, OUTPUT);
}
    
void loop() {
  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  float voltage = sensorValue * (5.0 / 1023.0);
  float voltage2 = voltage*(1023.0 / 5.0);
  Serial.println(voltage2);
  delay(1000);
  if (voltage2 < baselineVoltage) {
    if (belowBaselineVoltage == true) {
      if (millis() >= turnOnAt) {
        digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      } else {
      } else {
        belowBaselineVoltage = true;
        turnOnAt = millis() + turnOnDelay;
      }
    } else {
      belowBaselineVoltage = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You could improve your question. Please add comments about the reason why you code should enter a `if` or `else` path. This helps to understand your intention. Further please explain the reason for the 2 voltage variables, what are you calculating here?

Comment: I re-indented your code; you may want to have a look at the actual program flow.

Comment: @ocrdu I don't know what the code looked like before, but that brace/indentation style is horrible.  It would never pass any code review on the teams I run.

Answer (score 1):

State machines are very popular in embedded systems.  It makes the code behave in a predictable way, and that's invaluable when you do not have a debugger to step through the code.

Let's define your states.

1. motor_off:  Motor is OFF, read voltage, if voltage < 1V, go to time_low_voltage state.
2. time_low_voltage: Motor is OFF, read voltage, if voltage >= 1V go to state motor_off.  After 8 seconds in this state, go to motor_on state.
3. motor_on:  Motor is ON.  after 3 seconds, go to motor_off state.

We have 1 data item to keep track of, a timestamp of when the state has changed.

```
// **********************************
// shaker motor related definitions

enum class shaker_state : char
{
    motor_off, 
    time_low_voltage,
    motor_on,
};

struct shaker_data_t
{
    shaker_state state;
    unsigned int timestamp;

    // you could add here a small buffer to hold a few previous values
    // of ADC readings to do a bit of filtering...  The median of 5 filter 
    // should work very well here.  It is not absolutely needed for now, 
    // but you should consider having some kind of filter.  The motor may 
    // introduce noise in the readings. We'll just keep the last reading for
    // now.

    unsigned int adc_value;
};

// constants are declared constexpr to save memory space.
constexpr unsigned int SHAKER_TIMEOUT_LOW_VOLTAGE = 8000;  // in milliseconds
constexpr unsigned int SHAKER_TIMEOUT_MOTOR_ON    = 3000;  // .idem. 

// Again to save memory, and allow for DAC related constants
// to be computed at compile-time.  
constexpr inline float adc_value_to_volts(unsigned int value)
{
    return value * (5.f / 1024.f);
}

constexpr inline unsigned int volts_to_adc_value(float tension)
{
    return unsigned int(tension * (1024.f / 5.f));
}

constexpr unsigned int SHAKER_ADC_THRESHOLD = volts_to_adc_value(1.f);

constexpr int SHAKER_MOTOR = 2;
constexpr int SHAKER_ADC   = A0;

// **********************************
// global data

shaker_data_t shaker;

// **********************************

static void shaker_control()
{
  // always read adc.
  shaker.adc_value = analogRead(SHAKER_ADC);

  switch (shaker.state)
  {
  default:           // in case of catastrophic error, turn motor OFF.
  case shaker_state::motor_off:
      digitalWrite(SHAKER_MOTOR, LOW);
      if (shaker.adc_value < SHAKER_ADC_THRESHOLD)
      {
          shaker.state     = shaker_state::time_low_voltage;      
          shaker.timestamp = (unsigned int)millis();
      }
      break;

  case shaker_state::time_low_voltage:
      digitalWrite(SHAKER_MOTOR, LOW);
      if (shaker.adc_value >= SHAKER_ADC_THRESHOLD)
      {
          shaker.state = shaker_state::motor_off;
      }
      else if ((unsigned int)millis() - shaker.timestamp >= SHAKER_TIMEOUT_LOW_VOLTAGE)
      {
          digitalWrite(SHAKER_MOTOR, HIGH);
          shaker.state     = shaker_state::motor_on;
          shaker.timestamp = (unsigned int)millis();
      }
      break;

  case shaker_state::motor_on:
      digitalWrite(SHAKER_MOTOR, HIGH);
      if ((unsigned int)millis() - shaker.timestamp >= SHAKER_TIMEOUT_MOTOR_ON)
      {
          digitalWrite(SHAKER_MOTOR, LOW);
          shaker.state     = shaker_state::motor_off;
          shaker.timestamp = (unsigned int)millis();
      }
      break;
  }
}

// **********************************

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);

  digitalWrite(SHAKER_MOTOR, LOW);
  pinMode(SHAKER_MOTOR, OUTPUT);

  shaker.state     = shaker_state::motor_off;
  shaker.timestamp = (unsigned int)millis();
}
    
// **********************************

void loop() 
{
    // get temp and control moror.
    shaker_control();

    // shaker_control is very fast and never blocks, so you have plenty 
    // of extra time to blink LEDs, read switches, etc...
}
```

[EDIT]

Here is a simple median of 5 filter that you can add to filter out unwanted noise on the ADC reading.

```
class median_of_5_filter
{
  public:
    void push(unsigned int value)
    {
        buffer_[next_] = value;
        if (++next_ >= 5)
            next_ = 0;
        compute();
    }

    unsigned int get() const 
    {
        return filtered_;
    }

  private:
    void compute()
    {
        // bubble sort, but only the first 3 elements

        unsigned int buf_copy[5] = { buffer_[0], buffer_[1], buffer_[2], 
                                     buffer_[3], buffer_[4] };

        for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            auto min_index = i;
            auto min_value = buf_copy[i];
            for (unsigned char j = i + 1; j < 5; ++j)
            {
                if (buf_copy[j] < min_value)
                {
                    min_value = buf_copy[j];
                    min_index = j;
                }
            }
            if (i != min_index)
                swap(buf_copy[i], buf_copy[min_index]);
        }
        filtered_ = buf_copy[2];
    }

    static void swap(unsigned int& a, unsigned int& b)
    {
        auto t = a;
        a = b;
        b = t;
    }

  private:
    unsigned int filtered_  = 0;
    unsigned char next_     = 0; 
    unsigned int buffer_[5] = {};
};
```

To use:

```
struct shaker_data_t
{
    // ...
    median_of_5_filter adc_value;
};

// when reading ADC...
shaker.adc_value.push(analogRead(SHAKER_ADC));

// to get filtered adc reading 
if (shaker.adc_value.get() < SHAKER_ADC_THRESHOLD)
```

Comment: I haven't run this code, but upvoted for two reasons: clarity compared to the mess above, and the very good idea of a finite state machine.  Having ten patents for embedded medical devices, I applaud this style.  At a glance this code is more readable, and much more amenable to running in test rig.  Refreshing.